# Why does deleting a gateway route and then re-adding it make routing suddenly work?

Tags: linux, routing, ethernet

I have Fedora 34 running with 2 ethernet nics (let's call them eth0 and eth1). The routing table at boot looks like:

```
$ sudo route
   default         _gateway        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
   default         thor            0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth1
   10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.0.0.0       U     101    0        0 eth0
   192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     100    0        0 eth1

$ sudo ip route
default via 192.168.100.1 dev eth1 proto static metric 100
default via 10.100.0.1 dev eth0 proto static metric 101
10.0.0.0/8 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.1 metric 101
192.168.0.0/16 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.100.1 metric 100
```

10.100.0.1 is my router

When I `ping yahoo.com`, I get a timeout.

HOWEVER, if I delete the eth0 default and re-add it with the same values:

```
$ sudo route del default eth0
$ sudo route add default gw 10.100.0.1 eth0
```

NOW, the ping works.

The resulting tables:

```
$ sudo route
default         _gateway        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
default         thor            0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth1
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.0.0.0       U     101    0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     100    0        0 eth1

$ sudo ip route
default via 10.100.0.1 dev eth0
default via 192.168.100.1 dev eth1 proto static metric 100
10.0.0.0/8 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.1 metric 101
192.168.0.0/16 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.100.1 metric 100
```

How are these 2 routes different? One works, the other does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The destination IP address matches *two* routes with the same network and prefix length (`default` meaning `0.0.0.0/0`). When this happens, the route with the lowest *metric* – i.e. the lowest cost – is the one that gets used.

In the first example, you aren't using 10.100.0.1 as the gateway at all – it has a metric of 101, so the OS ignores it and uses 192.168.100.1 as the gateway because its metric (100) is lower.

But in the second example, you've re-added the route without specifying a metric, so it is treated as if it had a metric of *zero*, i.e. highest possible priority.

Comment: I'm running into an issue in VMWare VSphere where the default GW interface drops which causes the default route to drop, and when it is re-added back it's metric is HIGHER than the existing (other) GW route so the desired default route doesn't get used.  I'm trying to find a solution to this problem whereby the desired default GW will always have the lowest metric of the two gateways that are defined.