# In Ubuntu Linux, How can I ensure a default Gateway's metric is lower than any other gateways?

Tags: linux, networking, routing

I'm running into an issue with a dual-nic VM (say eth0 and eth1).  For example, things work when the routing table looks like this:

```
$ sudo route -n
default         10.100.0.1        0.0.0.0         UG    20100      0        0 eth0
default         192.168.100.1     0.0.0.0         UG    20101      0        0 eth1
```

The default GW `10.100.0.1` handles all traffic including DNS lookups, etc.

Over the weekend something happens (I'm not sure what) but when I come on Monday, I see that my desired default GW now has a HIGHER metric so it is not used.

```
$ sudo route -n
default         192.168.100.1     0.0.0.0         UG    20101      0        0 eth1
default         10.100.0.1        0.0.0.0         UG    20102      0        0 eth0  <<< ISSUE 20102
```

The LAN segment 192.168.100.1 only has connectivity to hosts used for testing.  The default gateway is created automatically when I enable the NETWORK SEGMENT (I'm running this VM in vSphere).

The result is that my DNS servers are not reachable.  *The work around is to reboot the host, or drop and re-add the default gateway.*

This question explains the problem: [Why does deleting a gateway route and then re-adding it make routing suddenly work?](https://superuser.com/questions/1657153/why-does-deleting-a-gateway-route-and-then-re-adding-it-make-routing-suddenly-wo)

**I'm trying to find a solution to this problem.  The solution should ensure that the desired default GW will always have the lowest metric of the two gateways that are defined.**

## Searching for solutions

I'm haven't found the correct search term for the problem I'm having so I've been reading on how Linux gateways work which hasn't been helpful towards answering my question.

- Google [Search how to properly configure two gateways for a dual-nic linux host](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-e&q=how%20to%20properly%20configure%20two%20gateways%20for%20a%20dual-nic%20linux%20host)
- https://serverfault.com/questions/1117143/how-to-configure-2-x-nic-with-each-having-their-own-gateway
- https://www.wikihow.com/Add-or-Change-the-Default-Gateway-in-Linux

Comment: Why not just increase the secondary interface's metric instead?

Comment: A possible workaround is to have a couple of more specific routes covering all ip's instead of a default gateway - ie 0.0.0.0/1 and 128.0.0.0/1

Comment: @DanielB, Good point.  I'm open to that solution as well.  I'll update my question to include the solution whereby the secondary interface has a high metric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I would use ip route, not just route. iproute2 package will replace net-tools shortly.

While there are better solutions I could suggest, if I had more details about your setup, eg: re you using netplan, or are you interfaces configured with the older interface config.

This solution should work with any Ubuntu release.

create a file in /etc/network/if-up.d/ and make it executable by root

```
#!/bin/sh
# filename: eth1.sh

if [ "$IFACE" = eth1 ]; then
  ip route del default dev eth1
fi
```

Based on the extra info I would suggest the best solution is:

creating a file /etc/systemd/network/99-eth1.network

```
[Match]
Name=eth1

[Network]
Address=192.168.100.100/24 *change to be the ip address you need*
DHCP=no
DefaultRouteOnDevice=false
```

This will ensure that vSphere does not allocate the gateway via dhcp.  I suspect something changed in your vSphere, update, or setting change that resulted in your vm being allocated a gateway via dhcp.  Or for some reason, the order your nics were setup during boot changed.  If eth1 is setup first, then the route metric would add the cost of reaching the gateway address by eth1 to eth0, hence the higher metric.

If you want to 110% ensure eth0 is setup first, and has a lower metric you can also create the below file if eth0 receives its address via dhcp, if it is statically assigned, change DHCP to no below, and add the address section, and enter the gateway address

```
/etc/systemd/network/80-eth0.network

[Match]
Name=eth0
    
[Network]
DHCP=ipv4

[Route]
Gateway=_dhcp4
Metric=5
```

Comment: I'm not using `netplan` so the solution you posted works well for my situation.  I was wondering why when adding the interface a default route was being added.  I'm looking to see if the scripts in `/etc/network/if-up.d/*` make this happen.

Answer (score 0):

A coworker provided another solution which was to use the `nmcli` command line interface which was based on the answer in **Ask Ubuntu** here **[Set network interface metric to a fixed value](https://askubuntu.com/a/1401228/323009)**

The solution sets the metric on the the desired interface **eth0** in the question to a low value.

NOTE: I'm not sure how/why the lower metric is maintained when the **eth0** interface is bounced but it did work when testing it out.

```
nmcli c eth0
set ipv4.route-metric 5
save
quit
systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

Both this answer and the selected answer worked for the OP.